# send an email with attached file via html

Tags: html, email, file-upload

I want to send an e-mail with attachment using just html ,can I do that(because I dont have a server just static)?

I want to upload the file and e-mail it not store it, the code below store the file on disk is it possible to send it via mail?

```
<form action="fileinsert.html" method="post">
<p>
Enter Your Text :<br>
<input type="text" name="textwrite" size="15">
</p>
<p>
Specify your File:<br>
<input type="file" name="datasize" size="30">
</p>
<div>
<input type="submit" value="Send">
</div>
</form>
```

is this doable with just html?

Comment: To upload files use `<form enctype="multipart/form-data">`.. [More information here](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/fileupload.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't do this with pure HTML.

To send E-Mails you need a PHP-Script on the server which collects the data from your form and send it:

```
<?php
mail($_POST['to'], $ubject, $message);
?>
```

This is just a little example of how using the mail-function and not a functional snippet for your problem, see for more information see [mail() function](http://php.net/manual/function.mail.php)

You also should have a look at [Mail_Mime](http://pear.php.net/package/Mail_Mime/redirected).

As Chris Peter says there is more than one way to do it: You can use Ruby, Perl, Python, .NET and even C for accomplishing this task.

Comment: PHP is not the only solution. You can also do it with Ruby, .NET, Node, and any other server-side solution. Good answer though!